# Python - How to get first item in list on list in python3

Tags: list, python-3.x, element

I have a list in python like the following:

```
edge =  [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [3, 4]]
```

I want to print `1` and `1` and `1` and `3`; aka the first element of each sub-list.

I use this code:

```
for subList in edge:
    for firstItem in subList:
        print(firstItem)
```

But it prints all elements..

Comment: Printing all first elements using list comprehension, `print([x[0] for x in edge])`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looping over all elements of all nested lists. If you only wanted to print the first element of each nested list, use indexing:

```
for sublist in edge:
    print(sublist[0])
```

If all nested lists have the same number of elements you could use unpacking:

```
for start, end in edge:
    print(start)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def first_item_generator(edge):
    for sublist in edge:
        yield sublist[0]

edge = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [3, 4]]
generator = first_item_generator(edge)
first_items = list(generator)

print(first_items)
```

The function generates and yields the first items from each sublist. Then,I created a generator object using this function and converted it to a list using list(generator) to get the final list of first items.